# how to fix typescript error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
const a = {
  '/app/developer-tools/API-keys': '/app/developer-tools/API-keys',
  '/app/developer-tools/API-reference': '/app/developer-tools/API-reference',
  '/app/engage': '/app/engage',
};

export const modifiedPaths = Object.keys(a).reduce((acc, key) => {
  const modifiedKey = key.replace("/app/", "");
  acc[modifiedKey] = a[key];
  return acc;
}, {});
```

I get the typescript error:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

Comment: Add typing to the arguments of reduce anonymous callback function

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to add typing.

```
const a: {[key:string]: string} = {
  '/app/developer-tools/API-keys': '/app/developer-tools/API-keys',
  '/app/developer-tools/API-reference':
    '/app/developer-tools/API-reference',
  '/app/engage': '/app/engage',
}

export const modifiedPaths = Object.keys(a).reduce((acc: {[key:string]: string}, key: string) => {
  const modifiedKey = key.replace('/app/', '');
  acc[modifiedKey] = a[key];
  return acc;
}, {});
```